# How do I set a property based on condition that a user has selected a feature in WIX?

Tags: wix, properties, conditional-statements

I want to set a property to be used after the FeaturesDlg (the one with the
feature tree) , based on condition that an user selected a feature or
not. Is this possible?

I've declared a new property, but I don't know how to set its value (that feature is enabled/disabled on feature tree).

Answer (score 3):

I was able to interrogate it using

```
<![CDATA[&FeatureName=3]]>
```

This would give a true value if it had been selected in the feature tree

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom action that will evaluate the feature's state and action (i.e. is it currently installed or not, and is the action to install it or not) and then set the property accordingly.

Then schedule the custom action to run in the right sequence.